# Οperational Research And linear Programming-The Houses Builder Problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mathematical-modeling

**EXERCISE**

> A builder has purchased $21,000$ square meters of land on which it is planned to build two types of houses, X(detached) and Y(a combination of town-house units), within an overall budget of $2100000$ euros.
>
> A type X house costs $35000$ euros to build and requires $600$ square meters of land. A type Y house cost $60000$ euros to build and requires $300$ square meters of land.
>
> To comply with local planning regulations, not more than $40$ buildings may be constructed on this land, but there must be at least five of each type. From past experience, it is known that the profit per type X house is about $10000$ euros and per type Y house to be about $6000$ euros.Profit is to maximized

**QUESTION**

> The problem must be formulated in the form of linear programming and has to be solved in EXCEL by SOLVER. Based on this output, you have to state what the optimal solution is.

**ATTEMPT**

- **Definition Of The Variables**

X: Type X houses(Detached)

Y: Type Y houses(a combination of town-house units)

- **Objective Function**

Maximize problem(Profit is to maximized)
$$\textrm{Max profit} =10000X + 6000Y$$

- **Constraints**

$X+Y \leq 40$ **(Not more than $40$ Buildings)**

$600X+300Y \leq 21000$**(Square meters Constraint)**

$35000X+60000Y \leq 2100000$**(Land requirements)**

$X \geq 5$ **(At Least Five Of Each Type)**

$Y \geq 5$ **(At Least Five Of Each Type)**

**So, when I get these constraints in my excel, Solver can't find a feasible solution and I don't know why. Is there any problem with my mathematical modelling? I believe that the constraints are obvious from the exercise!**

This is my Formulation in Excel:
[image]

and this is the message when I use Solver to solve it and find MaxProf:
[image]

**I would be really grateful if somebody can help me with this as it's important for the next questions of my project! Any thorough solution or explanation would be really helpful!**

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is not math related. Better site maybe **super user** https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155487/if-i-had-a-question-with-excel-which-site-would-i-use/155488

Comment: I´ve done the same in excel. It gave me the same message. It seems that the program is not feasible. Have you tried to sketch the feasible solution space?

Comment: Υeah, but why? Did you use the same mathematical modelling as me? It seems impossible to me that the program is not feasible, because it's only the first question in my project. All the other questions depend on this question! Strange ha?

Comment: @callculus yeah and I didn't find any feasible solution!

Comment: It is clear that the problem has no solution. With a minimum of 5 houses of each, you don’t have enough land.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Sorry,i've made a mistake.It's $21000$ square meters of land not $2100$ so we have enough land!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a typo at the exercise. $\text{It is "A builder has purchased 21,00}$  $\color{red}{0}$ $\text{square meters of land}$ $\text{on which it is planned to build... "}$

But you have written it at your constraint: $600X+300Y \leq 21,000 \ \ $ **(Square meters Constraint)**

If you use this constraint the problem is feasible. This is what I got by using the Excel solver:

[image]

**Excel sheet with formulas**

[image]

**Input mask**

[image]

Comment: This is after using Solver?I use Sumproduct function,not Sum!Is this wrong?And what is these $1050000$ and $600000$??From where did you get these?

Comment: It is $30\cdot 35000=1,050,000$ for instance. And similar for y: $10\cdot 60,000=600,000$

Comment: So,i made mistake with the variables.I use 1 and 1 but that's wrong because i have a constraint that tells me that i have $Y \geq 5$ and $X \geq 5$.Right?

Comment: And why you use Sum function?

Comment: I don´t know what you mean by "1 and 1" here. But I think the only mistake you made is that you wrote 2100 instead of 21000.

Comment: In excel ,I use $21000$ haha!So that was only a typo! :(

Comment: I sum up the cells. First constraint: cell C5: **=c4*35000**, cell D5: **=d4*60000**. Then at cell e5 I´ve  built the sum of c5 and d5.

Comment: That´s was what I´ve written. :)

Comment: Sorry for all of these questions haha.But i have to find the optimal solution.

Comment: did you use Solver?

Comment: Can you give me your solution in excel before you use Solver?

Comment: No problem. We are here to help, especially on Christmas. Yeah, I´ve used the solver.

Comment: Before I have used the solver the values were x=0 and y=0. I can show you the input mask. Maybe this is what you want.

Comment: And which cell you use as formula in Solver?

Comment: and which cell you set as objective in solver*? LOL

Comment: Yeah can you show me the input mask?

Comment: I used the cell F11 as objective function. This is the sum of c11 and d11. And c11: =10000*c4 and d11: =6000*d4

Comment: @MagicK.Mamba I´ve added the input mask and additionally  a picture which shows the formulas.

Comment: Ok,I'll check it.Thanks for all of your Help.!Happy christmas!

Comment: @MagicK.Mamba, It is a simple LP problem.

Comment: @MagicK.Mamba You´re welcome. Merry Christmas to you as well!

Comment: @MagicK.Mamba If the checkbox for non-negativity is not available at your solver you have to add the constraints $x\geq 0$ and $y \geq 0$.  See [here](https://imgur.com/a/34D9lZi) how the checkbox look like.